# How to reference an external library in a multi-abi QT build

Tags: android, qt

In docs I've found usage of '$${abi}' expression in file path which should supposedly be replaced by the name of the current ABI for which binaries for the platform at hand are requested. It doesn't seem to work for me.[image]

Here I've replaced occurrences of 'armeabi-v7a' with it and the build process complains in the following way:
":-1: error: No rule to make target 'E:*\jniLibs\libbotan-2.a', needed by 'lib*_armeabi-v7a.so'. Stop."

Seems like the expression resulted in an empty string (notice '' in place of $${abi}, ideas?
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

otherwise for arm7 it works but of course for deployment to store now we need x64 build as well thus the reason why I need a multi-abi build this time.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be used like this:

```
for (abi, ANDROID_ABIS): ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS += $$PWD/library_name_$${abi}.so
```

Reference: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs